# Is it true that $\lim_{n}p_{ij}^{(n)}=0$ for transient $j$?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

For a discrete-time Markov chain that is not necessarily irreducible or aperiodic, I am attempting to show that for transient $j$
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}p_{ij}^{(n)} = 0.
\end{equation*}
There is a well known result that states if
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}<\infty,
\end{equation*}
then $a_{n}\to 0$. Since the $p_{ij}^{(n)}$ are a sequence of numbers, if we use that for transient $j$
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p_{ij}^{(n)} <\infty
\end{equation*}
is it possible to deduce that
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}p_{ij}^{(n)} = 0?
\end{equation*}

I am slightly doubtful in the above statement as there is another well known result (see, e.g., pg. 127 Theorem 8.8 in Billingsley's Probability and Measure 2nd Ed.) that states $p_{ij}^{(n)}\to 0$ for all $i$, $j$ in an irreducible, aperiodic chain which is transient. Another post, [Prove that the limiting probability of a transient state in a Discrete Time Markov Chain, is 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2993182/887187), appears to have asked the same question but the only answer to the question refers to the previously mentioned result for irreducible, aperiodic chains. However, the result that I am trying to prove seems intuitive so I am having trouble understanding why it would not be true. My first thought is that maybe there is a misunderstanding in what is being asked in the question linked, as there appears to be possibly a slight difference in quantifiers unless I am misunderstanding. My second thought is that maybe the question in the provided link should be phrased such that $p_{jj}^{(n)}\to 0$ for transient state $j$, since we know that
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n\geq 0}p_{jj}^{(n)} < \infty
\end{equation*}
for transient $j$.

I am primarily looking to see if anyone can confirm if the approach above would work to prove the statement, or if anyone can provide a counterexample using the fact that the chain must be irreducible and aperiodic to show that this is a necessary condition for $p_{ij}^{(n)}\to 0$ for transient $j$.

** Edit: definition of transient state is
\begin{equation*}
f_{ii} = P(X_{n} =i,\ n\geq 1\mid X_{0}=i) < 1.
\end{equation*}

Comment: What you said is correct, once you assume $\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_{ij}^{(n)}$ converges, you necessarily get $p_{ij}^{(n)} \to 0.$

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you by chance know if it true that $\sum_{n}p_{ij}^{(n)}<\infty$ for transient $j$? Numerical examples seem to indicate that $p_{ij}^{(n)}\to 0$ for transient $j$, even in the non-irreducible and non-ergodic case, but if it is in fact true then I am unsure why the added assumptions are needed.

Comment: The internet (idk your definition) defines a state $i$ as transient (idk your definition, so here is one) $f_{ii} :=P(X_n=i \text{ for some n} \geq 1|X_0=i) < 1.$ Assume WLOG $p_{ii} = 0$ (no lazy markov chains.) Try computing the expected number of visits to state $i$ using the Markov chain definition, and using a geometric random variable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The definition you are using matches the one that I am using. The question has been updated accordingly using the definition you provided. I will give what you mentioned a try and if I still have questions will come back.